# Pandoc markdown to pdf: table with borders and lines between cells without intermediate latex tweeking

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I have document I have been writing in markdown that contains pipe tables in it. I convert this markdown document to pdf format and the tables are rendered in classic Latex style with no borders or lines between table cells. I would like to have the tables rendered with borders and lines between the cells. Is there a way to do this with a single pandoc command? Something like:

```
pandoc SOME_FLAGS_HERE_CONTROLLING_TABLE_STYLE -o output.pdf input.md
```

The only answers I have found that have come close to this involve first generating an intemediate Latex version of the file, modifying the Latex options to get the borders and grid lines, then generating the pdf from the intermediate Latex file.

I'm using pandoc version 1.16.02 and TexLive on Ubuntu.

Comment: First, the current pandoc is 2.6. Second, use a template (see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) or inject something with `--include-in-header`.